# The training labels in kitti dataset

Tags: python, matlab, computer-vision, training-data, point-clouds

I want to know what are the 14 values for each object in the kitti training labels. When I label the objects in matlab, i get 4 values for each object viz (x,y,width,height).

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: The first result if you Google "kitti training labels" is a GitHub issue with linked documentation which lists all of the attributes with descriptions: [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/v4.0.0-rc.3/digits/extensions/data/objectDetection/README.md).

Comment: You might want to accept the answer.

Answer (score 15):

**frame** Position of the sample within the sequence

**track id** Tracking ID of the object within the sequence

**type** Object type: ’Car’, ’Pedestrian’, ’Cyclist’, ’Tram’,
’Person_sitting’, ’Misc’ or ’DontCare’

**truncated** Integer (0,1,2) indicating the level of truncation.

**occluded** Integer (0,1,2,3) indicating occlusion state.

**alpha** Observation angle of object, ranging [-Pi; Pi]

**bbox 2D** (0-based) bounding box of the object:
Left, top, right, bottom image coordinates

**dimensions** 3D object dimensions: height, width, length [m]

**location** 3D object location x,y,z in camera coords. [m]

**rotation_y** Rotation around Y-axis in camera coords. [-Pi; Pi]

> In your case the four Labels you get are a transformed Version of the
>   **bbox 2D** Labels of the [KITTI groundtruth](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/v4.0.0-rc.3/digits/extensions/data/objectDetection/README.md)